# jquery element click event only allowed once? confuddled

Tags: jquery, click, element

One a click event of an element, it only works once. Say the value is 2 it will increase/decrease/reset only once.

How to I reset the event so the user can keep clicking on the element increasing the value of the value `.item-selection-amount`

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(event) {
        var amount = $(this).val();
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //set new value +
                $(this).val(amount + 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                //set new value reset
                $(this).val(0);
                break;
            case 3:
                //set new value -
                if(amount > 0){ 
                    $(this).val(amount - 1);
                }
                break;
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: This shouldn't happen the way you're describing it. Can you post a jsFiddle replicating the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript *cleverly* (read: it was a bad idea) overloaded the `+` operator to mean arithmetic addition and string concatenation.

If one of the operands looks like a string, it will do string concatenation. Your value looks like a string, so it does that.

I have used `parseInt(val, 10)` to try and get the integer, or get `0` if we get back something like `NaN` (not a number). The second argument to `parseInt()` is the radix. Without that, a number entered as `072` will be read in octal (base 8) format and probably not what yo want.

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(event) {
        var amount = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                //set new value +
                $(this).val(amount + 1);
                break;
            case 2:
                //set new value reset
                $(this).val(0);
                break;
            case 3:
                //set new value -
                if(amount > 0){ 
                    $(this).val(amount - 1);
                }
                break;
        }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DUCY3/).

#### Update

The right click event, `case 3`, would not work for me with Chrome, so I binded it to the `contextmenu` event and it worked...

```
$('.item-selection-amount').click(function(event) {
    var amount = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
    switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
        //set new value +
        $(this).val(amount + 1);
        break;
    case 2:
        //set new value reset
        $(this).val(0);
        break;
    case 3:
        //set new value -
        if (amount > 0) {
            $(this).val(amount - 1);
        }
        break;
    }
}).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var amount = parseInt($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
    if (amount > 0) {
        $(this).val(amount - 1);
    }
})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/CRYp7/).

Comment: nicework @alex - i noticed it was doing the concatenation as you stated, making the inputs as 1111111 instead of 7 :). although it still doesn't work for case 2 / 3...